# How to differentiate Unity Purchase from Restore Purchase?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, appsflyer

I'm trying to implement unity iap and I need to send PaymentSucceed event to my analytics in order to track purchases!

I'm Calling PaymentSucceed event in my

```
 public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
```

function, but the issue is that when user re-installs application the ProcessPurchase event is called again on android to restore purchases, and sents event for my analytics, but that's not a revenue event, so that's not correct to count it as Payment, can you share please some thoughts how I can understand is it restore or actual payment in the correct way?

here is my ProcessPurchase script

```
public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
    {
        // A consumable product has been purchased by this user.
     
        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDNoAds, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("noads",1);
            BannerAdManager.Instance.HideBanner();
            CheckNoAds();
           
        var prodID = args.purchasedProduct.definition.id;
        var price = ReplaceCommas(args.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedPrice.ToString());
        var currency = args.purchasedProduct.metadata.isoCurrencyCode;
        var receipt = args.purchasedProduct.receipt;
   
        var param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        param["af_quantity"] = "1";
        param["af_content_type"] = "general";
           
        var recptToJSON = (Dictionary<string, object>)AFMiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(receipt);
        var receiptPayload = (Dictionary<string, object>)AFMiniJSON.Json.Deserialize((string)recptToJSON["Payload"]);
           
        var purchaseData = (string)receiptPayload["json"];
        var signature = (string)receiptPayload["signature"];

        Debug.LogError("Purchase Event Sent Start");
       
        AppsFlyerAndroid appsFlyerAndroid = new AppsFlyerAndroid();
        appsFlyerAndroid.validateAndSendInAppPurchase(
            "111",
            signature,
            purchaseData,
            price,
            currency,
            param,
            this);
       
        Debug.LogError("Purchase Event Sent Finish");
 
       PaymentSucceed(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id,args.purchasedProduct.metadata.isoCurrencyCode,(float)args.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedPrice,"noads");
 
        }
        // Or ... an unknown product has been purchased by this user. Fill in additional products here....
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        }

        // Return a flag indicating whether this product has completely been received, or if the application needs
        // to be reminded of this purchase at next app launch. Use PurchaseProcessingResult.Pending when still
        // saving purchased products to the cloud, and when that save is delayed.
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this (i was looking for this just now) resides in the [Product](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.9/api/UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product.html#properties) class (from docs):

**hasReceipt**

> Owned Non Consumables and Subscriptions should always have receipts. Consumable's receipts are not persisted between App restarts unless it has a pending transaction. Once a consumable has been acknowledged (ConfirmPendingPurchase) the receipt is removed.

**receipt**

> The purchase receipt for this product, if owned. For consumable purchases, this will be the most recent purchase receipt. Consumable's receipts are not set between app restarts unless it has a pending transaction. Once a consumable has been acknowledged (ConfirmPendingPurchase) the receipt is removed. Receipts is in JSON format.

If you receive a consumable product on restore phase with receipt, its a pending product. If no receipt, its just restoring a previous bought.

Comment: Seems fair to me, for now I just added flag, "isRestore" which is true, when you open game, and becomes true, when you click on any type of but button.